# Why can't I draw text via GlyphRunDrawing class in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to draw a circle with text in it. I decided to use `GeometryGroup` class for that. I'm trying to do something like this:

1. Make circle object via `EllipseGeometry` class
2. Make text object via `GlyphRunDrawing` class
3. Add circle and text in `GeometryGroup`
4. Make `DrawingImage` object from `GeometryGroup` object
5. Set field "Source" of `Image` to `DrawingImage`

---

- I can't add `GlyphRunDrawing` object to `GeometryGroup`; Visual Studio says, that it can't convert `System.Windows.Media.GlyphRunDrawing` to `System.Windows.Media.Geometry`.

  - Why?
- `EllipseGeometry` and `GlyphRunDrawing` are both coming from `Geometry` class, `EllipseGeometry` I can convert.
- How can I add text to `GeometryGroup`?

Actual code:

```
var Circle1 = new EllipseGeometry(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 100)));
var GlyphRun = new GlyphRun();
var Glyph = new GlyphRunDrawing(Brushes.Black, GlyphRun);

var gg = new GeometryGroup();
gg.Children.Add(Circle1);
gg.Children.Add(Glyph); //Error

var gd = new GeometryDrawing();
gd.Brush = Brushes.LightBlue;
gd.Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
gd.Geometry = gg;

var rectangleImage = new DrawingImage(gd);
myImage.Source = rectangleImage;
```

Comment: Please show us your actual code.

Comment: @Dai done. I know, that I need to add something in Glyph, but compiler already says, that code is wrong.

Comment: [GlyphRunDrawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.glyphrundrawing) does not inherit `Geometry` but `Drawing`. You can combine multiple Drawings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-composite-drawing

Comment: Far simpler, draw a TextBlock on top of an Ellipse or a Path with an EllipseGeometry.